# Conditional combined sum in LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this table that I access throught linq-to-entities:

- Day
- Amount
- Type (1 or 2)

I have many rows on the same day and of the same type and I need to summarize their amounts by month. That's easy:

```
from r in rows
group r by new { r.Date.Year, r.Date.Month }
into g
select
    new
        {
            Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
            Hours = g.Sum(a => a.Amount)
        };
```

However, I have a special rule that I need to implement in the same LINQ, that I would like some help with:

If there is ANY type 2 on a given day, then THAT day should only sum of type 2. Otherwise it should summarize on type 1.

Notice that the distinction between type 1 and type 2 is per day and the sum is per month.

**UPDATE**
As I'm dealing with a LOT of data, I need to get it all in one database call, I cannot load it into memory and manage it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rows
    .GroupBy(
        r => new { r.Date.Year, r.Date.Month, r.Date.Day, r.Type },
        (r, rr) => new { r.Year, r.Month, r.Day, r.Type, Amount = rr.Sum(rrr => rrr.Amount) })
    .GroupBy(
        r => new { r.Year, r.Month, r.Day },
        (r, rr) => new { r.Year, r.Month, r.Day, Amount = rr.OrderByDescending(rrr => rrr.Type).Select(rrr => rrr.Amount).First() })
    .GroupBy(
        r => new { r.Year, r.Month },
        (r, rr) => new { r.Year, r.Month, Amount = rr.Sum(rrr => rrr.Amount) })
```

**Ratio behind this** is very simple: the requirement "if there's at least one type 2 record, sum only type 2 records" can be implemented by simply grouping records by type (within days, of course). Why does it work? Because we split all records into two groups, type 2 (which should be used if there is at least one type 2 record), and type 1 (which in fact means "all records when no type 2 present"). Second part (choosing sum) is even simpler: we just order groups (within day) by descending type (i.e. sum for type 2, sum for type 1) and take first one, which gives us type 2 if present and type 1 otherwise.

Frankly, it's a kind of "smart code" everybody hates, because nobody could understand from a glance how it works.

Comment: Can you please try it on your dataset?

Comment: Thank you. Frankly, I did it without db check.

Comment: Serg, it works! Very nicely done. Now I'll try to understand what is actually happening :)

Comment: I'll add ratio behind it to my answer.

Comment: You have a point about the fact, that it's not easily understandable. I was thinking rewriting it to the pretty LINQ format, to see if it might be easier to read then ...

Comment: As it turns out - unless I am mistaken: When you run "First" it is taken into memory and the rest of the LINQ happens in memory. This means that thousands of rows for days are fetched from the SQL Server...

Comment: If you mean `First` inside second `GroupBy`, it is not "run", it is a part of `Expression` tree. So it seems you're mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

How would this look to you?

```
var query =
    from r in rows.ToArray()
    group r by new { r.Date.Year, r.Date.Month } into g
    let lookup = g.ToLookup(x => x.Type, x => x.Amount)
    let Hours = lookup[2].Any() ? lookup[2].Sum() : lookup[1].Sum()
    select new
    {
        Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
        Hours,
    };
```

Note the `.ToArray()` as you need to bring your data into memory to make this work.

I assumed that `Type` was an integer with values of either `1` or `2`.

---

On further thought I don't think it is possible to do this kind of grouping in a single query without bringing it into memory.

So the best alternative is to minimize the memory. If this doesn't work then you'll need to break it down into several queries.

```
var query1 =
    from r in rows
    group r.Amount by new
    {
        r.Date.Year,
        r.Date.Month,
        r.Type,
    } into g
    select new
    {
        g.Key.Year,
        g.Key.Month,
        g.Key.Type,
        Amount = g.Sum(),
    };

var query2 =
    from r in query1.ToArray()
    group r by new
    {
        r.Year,
        r.Month,
    } into g
    let lookup = g.ToLookup(x => x.Type, x => x.Amount)
    let Hours = lookup[2].Any() ? lookup[2].Sum() : lookup[1].Sum()
    select new
    {
        Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
        Hours,
    };
```

Is this a option a possibility?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I cannot load the data into memory. I have updated the answer. Sorry for not specifying that initially.

Comment: It is so much that I do not want to put it in memory.

Comment: I've had a further thought and modified my answer. It is a compromise but it might work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Wouldn't this be a distinction on type per month instead of per day? In the first query I think you lose the information about types on individual days.

Comment: The `query1` captures the `Type` value in the first grouping, so it shouldn't lose it.

Comment: Yes, but the first grouping is by month, so the result will be "May is type 1" and "June is type 2", but in reality, June 29 and be type 1 and June 30 can be type 2.

Comment: The first grouping of my updated queries is year, month & type. It should work fine.

Comment: So it will show 2012, May, Type 2. But May may contain different types on individual days, so it does not make sense to conclude that May is Type 2.

Comment: It then groups by type in `query2` which correctly separates them out. Did you try the queries to see if they work in your code?

Comment: No, I used Serg's answer. But tell me, doesn't query1 group by year/month/type? In that case, how can you later group by type on a DAILY basis in query2, when query2 only uses the result from query1?

Comment: Since you were summing all of the values by type it didn't matter if I did it in `query1` or `query2`, but doing it in `query1` reduced the memory footprint and you said that was important.

Comment: I'm not summing all the values by type. I'm summing each day by type and then using type 2 if it's there and otherwise using type 1 - for that specific day. Even if the total sum is based on a month.

Comment: Ah, missed that, sorry. Thought it was if there was one type two for the month and not per day. No wonder there are some complicated answers.

Comment: Thanks for your attention though and sticking with it :) btw, try reading my comments again and see if you can see what I was trying to explain ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I've got this figured out. I've tested it with some data, and that works.

Testdata and SQL testquery:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (
    Datum DATETIME,
    Amount INT,
    [Type] INT
)

INSERT INTO @table (Datum, Amount, [Type]) values
('2012-01-01',200,1),
('2012-01-01',100,2),
('2012-01-02',500,1),
('2012-03-01',200,1),
('2012-03-01',100,1),
('2012-03-02',500,2)

SELECT MONTH(Datum), YEAR(Datum), COUNT(*), SUM(Amount)
FROM @table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DAY (Datum) AS _day, MONTH(Datum) AS _month, YEAR(Datum) _year,
    MAX([Type]) as _type
    FROM @table
    GROUP BY DAY (Datum), MONTH(Datum), YEAR(Datum)
) X
ON _month = MONTH (T.Datum)
AND _year = YEAR(T.Datum)
AND _day = DAY(T.Datum)
AND _type = T.[Type]
GROUP BY MONTH(Datum), YEAR(Datum)
```

Result:

```
(No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)    (No column name)
1   2012    2   600
3   2012    3   800
```

The translated LINQ query, tested with L2S and a 'real' test-table with test-data.

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext ctx = new DataClasses1DataContext()) {
    var rows = ctx.Tests;

    var query = rows
        .Join(
            rows.GroupBy(rr =>
                new { rr.Datum.Day, rr.Datum.Month, rr.Datum.Year },
                (key, data) => new { Year = key.Year, Month = key.Month, Day = key.Day, MaxType = data.Select(xxx => xxx.Type).Max() }
            ),
            rr => new { Day = rr.Datum.Day, Month = rr.Datum.Month, Year = rr.Datum.Year, Type = rr.Type },
            rr => new { Day = rr.Day, Month = rr.Month, Year = rr.Year, Type = rr.MaxType },
            (r, r1) => r

        )
        .GroupBy(r =>
            new { Year = r.Datum.Year, Month = r.Datum.Month },
            (key, data) => new { Year = key.Year, Month = key.Month, Amount = data.Select(xx => xx.Amount).Sum() }
        )
        .ToList();
}
```

This returns the same results.

And, for the fun of it, the SQL-query that L2S generated from the Linq query.

```
SELECT [t7].[value] AS [Year], [t7].[value2] AS [Month], (
    SELECT SUM([t8].[Amount])
    FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t8]
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [t11].[value3], [t11].[value2], [t11].[value], (
            SELECT MAX([t12].[Type])
            FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t12]
            WHERE ((([t11].[value] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t12].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t11].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t12].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t11].[value] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t12].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t11].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t12].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t11].[value] = DATEPART(Day, [t12].[Datum])))))) AND ((([t11].[value2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t12].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t11].[value2] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t12].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t11].[value2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t12].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t11].[value2] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t12].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t11].[value2] = DATEPART(Month, [t12].[Datum])))))) AND ((([t11].[value3] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t12].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t11].[value3] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t12].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t11].[value3] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t12].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t11].[value3] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t12].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t11].[value3] = DATEPART(Year, [t12].[Datum]))))))
            ) AS [value4]
        FROM (
            SELECT [t10].[value], [t10].[value2], [t10].[value3]
            FROM (
                SELECT DATEPART(Day, [t9].[Datum]) AS [value], DATEPART(Month, [t9].[Datum]) AS [value2], DATEPART(Year, [t9].[Datum]) AS [value3]
                FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t9]
                ) AS [t10]
            GROUP BY [t10].[value], [t10].[value2], [t10].[value3]
            ) AS [t11]
        ) AS [t13] ON (DATEPART(Day, [t8].[Datum]) = [t13].[value]) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t8].[Datum]) = [t13].[value2]) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t8].[Datum]) = [t13].[value3]) AND ([t8].[Type] = [t13].[value4])
    WHERE ((([t7].[value] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t8].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t7].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t8].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t7].[value] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t8].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t7].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t8].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[value] = DATEPART(Year, [t8].[Datum])))))) AND ((([t7].[value2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t8].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t7].[value2] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t8].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t7].[value2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t8].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t7].[value2] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t8].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t7].[value2] = DATEPART(Month, [t8].[Datum]))))))
    ) AS [Amount]
FROM (
    SELECT [t6].[value], [t6].[value2]
    FROM (
        SELECT DATEPART(Year, [t0].[Datum]) AS [value], DATEPART(Month, [t0].[Datum]) AS [value2]
        FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT [t3].[value3], [t3].[value2], [t3].[value], (
                SELECT MAX([t4].[Type])
                FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t4]
                WHERE ((([t3].[value] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t4].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t4].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[value] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t4].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[value] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Day, [t4].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[value] = DATEPART(Day, [t4].[Datum])))))) AND ((([t3].[value2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t4].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[value2] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t4].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[value2] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t4].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[value2] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t4].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[value2] = DATEPART(Month, [t4].[Datum])))))) AND ((([t3].[value3] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t4].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[value3] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t4].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ((([t3].[value3] IS NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t4].[Datum]) IS NULL)) OR (([t3].[value3] IS NOT NULL) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t4].[Datum]) IS NOT NULL) AND ([t3].[value3] = DATEPART(Year, [t4].[Datum]))))))
                ) AS [value4]
            FROM (
                SELECT [t2].[value], [t2].[value2], [t2].[value3]
                FROM (
                    SELECT DATEPART(Day, [t1].[Datum]) AS [value], DATEPART(Month, [t1].[Datum]) AS [value2], DATEPART(Year, [t1].[Datum]) AS [value3]
                    FROM [dbo].[Test] AS [t1]
                    ) AS [t2]
                GROUP BY [t2].[value], [t2].[value2], [t2].[value3]
                ) AS [t3]
            ) AS [t5] ON (DATEPART(Day, [t0].[Datum]) = [t5].[value]) AND (DATEPART(Month, [t0].[Datum]) = [t5].[value2]) AND (DATEPART(Year, [t0].[Datum]) = [t5].[value3]) AND ([t0].[Type] = [t5].[value4])
        ) AS [t6]
    GROUP BY [t6].[value], [t6].[value2]
    ) AS [t7]
```

I have no idea how efficient this SQL is, you're going to have to try it.

Comment: Maarten, thankyou for a very nice and thorough answer that I could probably have easily used. I chose to try Serg's answer first, because the LINQ is just prettier :)

Comment: Fair enough! It is the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
from r in rows
group r by new { r.Date.Year, r.Date.Month }
into g
let type2Days = g.Where( a => a.Type == 2 ).Select( a => a.Date.Day ).Distinct()
let filtered = g.Where( a => a.Type == 2 || type2Days.Contains(a.Date.Day) == false )
select
    new
        {
            Date = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
            Hours = filtered.Sum(a => a.Amount)
        };
```

Comment: Nicely done. It's quite logical and readable. However, you first group into g and then you filter using g. Would that work? We need the type on a per day basis.

Comment: @ Niels It should work.  For each month it will get the rows that are either type 2 or are on a day that doesn't have any type 2 rows.  If you wanted you could filter before grouping.  You would just have to use `Date.Date` instead of `Date.Day`.